# Is the assignment expression after "sizeof" never executed?

Tags: c, expression, sizeof

e.g.

```
    int a = 3;
    int b = sizeof(++a);
    int c = a;
```

Is c equal to 3 or 4 as the result?
Does the result depend on the specific compiler?

Comment: There is nothing creative or constructive in this question . The answer could have been easily found out on the SO itself .

Answer (score 0):

The specification states that the increment operator does **NOT** take affect when used within a `sizeof` operator.

This also makes sense from an abstract viewpoint.  Specifically, the `sizeof` operator returns the number of bytes used by an object.  While incrementing an integer or even a pointer does **NOT** change the size of that integer, the ++ operator would mis-lead a new programmer into thinking the size does change.

If interested look-up the topic "side-effects" for more discussion about this subject.